# Using Javascript to read and display a txt file dynamically

Tags: javascript

I was trying to read a txt file and display its content in my web page, since its content changes over time, I want to update it periodically. Here is my code, it displays the content at first, but it won't change after I changed the file's content. Any suggestions? Thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        setTimeout(read(),3000);
    function read(){
    setTimeout(jQuery.get('now.txt',function(data){
    document.write(data);}),1000);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nearly there. Change:

```
setTimeout('read', 3000);
           ^^^^^ here
```

and here:

```
function read(){
    jQuery.get('now.txt',function(data){document.write(data);});
}
```

If you want it to refresh every 3 seconds use `setInterval`

Documentation:

- http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Comment: I tried with setInterval(read,3000); and it works! The problem right now is that it keeps adding the contents at the end. Is there anyway to wipe former data and just display the current content?

Comment: add `<div id="container"></div>` to your HTML and change `document.write(data)` to `$('#container').html(data);`

Answer (score 1):

the function name does not need to be closed. It also does not need to be a string.

change this

```
setTimeout(read(),3000);
```

to this

```
setTimeout(read, 3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your ajax results might be cached try setting `$.ajaxSetup({cache: false})`. Also I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with the `setTimeout`s, are you trying to load the page after 3+1 seconds?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajaxSetup({cache: false})
    setTimeout(read, 3000);
    function read(){
        jQuery.get('now.txt',function(data){
        document.write(data);});
    }
</script>
```