# Read contents of text file dynamically

Tags: jquery

I am trying to have HTML page display the values of a text file. If the values of the text file change, then have the HTML page display the updated contents realtime.

Here is what I have, based on a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062674/using-javascript-to-read-and-display-a-txt-file-dynamically):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(read,3000);
function read(){
setTimeout(jQuery.get("now.txt",function(data){
$('#container').html(data);}),1000);
}
```

I have `<div id="container"></div>` in the body.

I am not getting the page to display any contents. Can someone point out what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `setInterval` to redo things in a loop having certain time gap. And use `.load()` to load the text file.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#container').load("now.txt");
    setInterval(function(){
        $('#container').load("now.txt");
    },1000);
});
```