# How can I read from a local txt file and check when it changes in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to make my js program read from a txt file whose location is hardcoded. Every time the txt file is update, I want to store the new data as a new variable.
For example, when the txt file changes from blank to the following:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
```

it will store newInfo = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
Then if the txt file is updated to the following:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
consectetur adipiscing elit
```

It will store newInfo = "consectetur adipiscing elit"

Comment: This forum can be helpful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062674/using-javascript-to-read-and-display-a-txt-file-dynamically

Comment: You're doing this in Node.js? I think what you want is called watching a file, https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fswatchfilefilename-options-listener

Comment: I'm curious if you could use [JS read streams](https://www.tabnine.com/code/javascript/functions/fs/ReadStream/on) (assuming you're using Node.js?)... Would the `.on("data", () => {})` listener continue to update each time the file is changed?